# How to concatenate two integer arrays

Tags: c, arrays

This code:                           //no comment to add

```
int main(){                          //no comment to add
                                     //no comment to add
                                      //no comment to add
float x[2] = {1,2};                  //array 1
float y[2] = {5,7 };                 //array 2 

float* total = (float*)malloc(4 * sizeof(float)); // array to hold the result
//no comment to add
memcpy(total,     x, 2 * sizeof(float)); // copy 2 floats from x to      //total[0]...total[1]
memcpy(total + 2, y, 2 * sizeof(float)); // copy 2 floats from y to //total[2]...total[3]
//no comment to add
//no comment to add
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){                              //no comment to add
    printf("the value for total[%d] is %d\n",i,total[i]); //copy arrays  //x,y into the 'total' array.
}                                                   //no comment to add
```

return 0;//no comment to add
}       //no comment to add

```
   ///-----------------------------------------
   /// gives the result:

  /// the value for total[0] is 0;
  ///  the value for total[1] is 0;
  ///  the value for total[2] is 0;
  ///  the value for total[3] is 0;

  ///  and i want to get:

  /// the value for total[0] is 1;
  ///  the value for total[1] is 2;
  ///  the value for total[2] is 5;
  ///  the value for total[3] is 7;

  ///  Can someone give the correct code??
```

//no comment to add

Comment: I fail to see even a single integer array, let alone two.

Comment: (`//comment to add`) You're printing `float`s as `int`s. Try `%f` in the `printf` format.

Comment: What is this alien question formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier for `printf` with `%d` for a `float`.

You must use `%f` for `float` or `double`.

```
printf("the value for total[%d] is %f\n",i,total[i]);
```

Program output is now

```
the value for total[0] is 1.000000
the value for total[1] is 2.000000
the value for total[2] is 5.000000
the value for total[3] is 7.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with integer numbers only, I would suggest to replace all float's to int's:

```
int main()
{
    int x[2] = {1,2};
    int y[2] = {5,7};

    int* total = (int*)malloc(4 * sizeof(int));

    memcpy(total,     x, 2 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(total + 2, y, 2 * sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("the value for total[%d] is %d\n",i,total[i]);
    }

    free(total);

    return 0;
}
```